# Ripping out a blade of grass by a funeral?

Tags: minhag, sources-mekorot, funeral-burial-levaya, agriculture

At my great-uncle's funeral today, all of the participants (except the mourners) were told to rip out a blade of grass and say a *passuk* (I don't remember which).

Is this a Jewish minhag? If so, what is the source for it? What does it mean?

---

*Torah learned from this post should be a זכות for the נשמה of חיים בן יחזקאל*

Comment: Yes, I checked -- this has not been asked on this site before ;-) [at least not under [tag:funeral-burial-levaya]]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**You asked:** Is this a Jewish minhag? If so, what is the source for it?

Yes. it is mentioned in the Kitzur Shulchan Aruch [199:10](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_00561.html#HtmpReportNum0198_L2)  - סימן קצט - דין הקבורה ובית הקברות

"The custom - when leaving a cemetery - is to pluck some grass and throw it behind one's back, and say *זָכוּר כִּי עָפָר אֲנָחְנוּ* - *remember that we are dust*."

**You asked:** What does it mean?

Meaning #1, mentioned by the Kitzur:

"This is a reminder of לִתְחִיַת הַמֵּתִים - when the dead will come alive at the end of days - that the dead will row from the barren ground and suddenly peek up like grass."

Meaning #2, mentioned by the Kitzur:

"After leaving one washes one's hands. All this hints at the way one is purified from impurity caused by death: (1) water, mixed with (2) dust [ashes of the red heifer] and (3) grass representing the hyssop with which it was sprinkled on the impure one."

> **סעיף י'**:
>   נוֹהֲגִין שֶׁכְּשֶׁהוֹלְכִין מִבֵּית הַקְּבָרוֹת, **תּוֹלְשִׁין עֲשָׂבִים וּמַשְׂלִיכִין אַחֲרֵי גֵוָם** וְאוֹמְרִים, זָכוּר כִּי עָפָר אֲנָחְנוּ. וְגַם הוּא רֶמֶז לִתְחִיַת הַמֵּתִים, שֶׁיִחְיוּ מֵעֲפָרָם, עַל דֶּרֶךְ, וְיָצִיצוּ מֵעִיר כְּעֵשֶב הָאָרֶץ. וִיכוֹלִין לַעֲשׂוֹת כֵּן גַּם בְּחֹל הַמּוֹעֵד (מבי"ט חלק א סִימָן רג). וְרוֹחֲצִין יְדֵיהֶם. וְיֵשׁ רֶמֶז, שֶׁאֵין טֻמְאָה זֹאת נִטְהֶרֶת אֶלָּא בִּשִׁלשָׁה דְבָרִים אֵלּוּ, מַיִם וְאֵפֶר פָּרָה וְאֵזוֹב.‏

It is also mentioned in the Shulchan Aruch in [376:4](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01976_part_60.html#HtmpReportNum0034_L2) סימן שעו - מנהג המנחמין, ודין מת שאין לו מנחמים

Comment: Awesome answer, thanks! +1 and accepted. You'll have to show me how to use Torat Emet for direct links like that -- thus far I haven't been able to figure it out myself.

Comment: Never mind -- found [this page](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/a_root.html); I'm good now. Thanks again for your answer!

Answer (score 15):

On chabad.org [it says the following](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/368098/jewish/After-the-Burial.htm):

> On the way out of the cemetery, it is customary to pull out some
>   grass, throw it back over the shoulder, and recite the passage below.
>   This symbolizes the Resurrection of the Dead in the era of Moshiach,
>   when the body will awaken and return from the dust of the earth, as it
>   is written, "And may they blossom out of the city like grass of the
>   earth" ([Psalms 72:16](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16293#v=16)). As you toss the grass back over your shoulder,
>   say the following verse three times: ויציצו מעיר כעשב הארץ Some say
>   this instead: זכור כי עפר אנחנו

So, it is definitely a Jewish Minhag. As for the source and what it means besides for the above quote, the באר היטב in [Shulchan Aruch, Orach Chaim 224](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x1053) explained that the custom of plucking grass from the ground is in order to show honor the the deceased - that you visited him (although I think that he is referring to a visit later on).

Comment: My pleasure! BTW if i am not mistaken the Lubavitcher Rebbe would rip out some grass and toss it over his shoulder

Comment: how do you make that yellow line (i was trying to figure out how to do that?)

Comment: There's two (or three) ways to do that -- either highlight the paragraph and click the `"` button on top of the page; put a `>` symbol at the front of the line; or highlight a paragraph and hit `ctrl-Q` ....all end up doing the same thing, it's just whatever's easier for you to use ( I use `ctrl-Q` )